# Not able to access Bigquery dataset from .net app

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to GCP and have created a Project in GCP which has a service account with a principal associated with it.The principal has role of editor , owner and viewer. I have created a dataset which contains a table which i am not able to access from .net application.

Steps used to connect to read data from table :

1.Created service account to authenticate Api requests

2.Created key,json file which will be used by .net application to connect to the datasets(gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ~/key.json)

3.

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
string dir = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName + "\\"+"currency-342912-7c734b3fad06.json";
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(dir);
var client = BigQueryClient.Create("currency-342912", credential);
var table = client.GetTable("bigquery-public-data", "austin_311", "311_service_requests");
var sql = $"SELECT * FROM {table} LIMIT 10";
var results = client.ExecuteQuery(sql,parameters:null);
```

getting the below error :

Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Access Denied: Project bigquery-public-data: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project bigquery-public-data

But user has browser, editor , owner , viewer all the permissions

Comment: It looks like you're actually trying to query the `bigquery-public-data` project... in which case it should be possible to provide a [mcve] which shows the *exact* dataset you're trying to use.

Comment: Note that if you're specifying `bigquery-public-data` as the project ID when you create the `BigQueryClient`, you shouldn't - you should specify your *actual* project ID there, only specifying the public data project in the query. See this code for an example: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/main/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.Snippets/BigQueryClientSnippets.cs#L69

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thank you for the inputs . I am specifying the actual project Id .Editing my post which specifies the public dataset i am trying to access

Comment: @JonSkeet i also added few more roles to the project Bigquery.Admin/DataEditor/DataOwner/DataViewer/JobUser/User but still the error remains the same

Comment: Okay, I'll try to reproduce this tomorrow. But fundamentally, the problem shown by the error message is that you're trying create a job in the bigquery-public-data project, instead of your own project. I'll try to figure out why that is.

Comment: @JonSkeet for Fyi i also tried to access my own dataset created under the same project but still get the same issue . Also Project is not linked to any of the billing account , could this be the cause . Again thanks for looking into this

Comment: "Also Project is not linked to any of the billing account , could this be the cause" - not sure. Maybe. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce this. I've created a new project, removed the billing account, and created a new service account with the "BigQuery Admin" role, and it's able to query both a table in the same project and the public one you've shown. Are you *sure* that the service account you're loading the credentials for is the one with appropriate BigQuery access? Are you able to give it the "BigQuery Admin" role as a simple way of just giving all the permissions in one go? (I received the exact error you did until I granted my service account the role.)

Comment: @JonSkeet you were absolutely correct , i did not give appropriate roles to the service account . Roles were only given on Project level. Thanks for the help it worked

Comment: Great - glad it worked. I suspect this question could be made useful if you explained how you *thought* you'd given access, so you can then add an answer explaining how to *actually* give access.

Comment: @JonSkeet Could you please post the answer to help the community facing the same problem?

Comment: @RaulSaucedo: As I've suggested above, the OP is in a better position to do this. What they've described in the question ("But user has browser, editor , owner , viewer all the permissions") isn't actually the case - so it would be better for them to correct the question and then post the answer.

Comment: @Debasish22 Could you please post the answer to help the community facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error in the question above -"Access Denied: Project bigquery-public-data: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project bigquery-public-data"

it is mentioned to have the role "bigquery.jobs.create" so i applied this role at the project level and the only area left was the service account , i applied this role to the service account and this started working